# Hiding the Ionic Framework Header based on screen orientation

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, ionic-framework

I would like to ask if there is a way to hide a nav bar of the ionic framework on a particular view upon changing in the screen orientation from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, it's very easy.

This is a function you need to trigger to hide a navbar:

```
$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
```

Of course, do it inside an appropriate Controller.

The second part of this formula is Cordova Orientation plugin, click [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/changing-locking-screen-orientation-in-ionic-application/).

So when combined you would want something like this:

```
if(screen.orientation == 'landscape') {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false); 
}
```

There's also a JavaScript approach to detect an orientation, but it's a hit and miss solution on some devices. Cordova plugin i much safer solution.

This is not everything, what if user change orientation after view initialization:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

// Initial execution if needed
doOnOrientationChange();

function doOnOrientationChange()
{
    if(screen.orientation == 'landscape') {
        $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false); 
    }        
}
```