# Closing/Opening Ionic menu during screen orientation

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

I'm a newbie to Ionic framework. Is there a way to open the menu on the landscape mode, closing it while it changes to portrait mode and vice versa similar to this one, [Hiding the Ionic Framework Header based on screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346428/hiding-the-ionic-framework-header-based-on-screen-orientation).

By using,

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){

});
```

I can able to detect the orientation change but couldn't find a way to hide/show the menu. And is there way to do this using CSS'

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {

}
/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {

}
```

And if both are possible, which is the preferred way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the service `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` to open or close the menu programatically.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
//                                        ˆˆˆˆ injected ˆˆˆˆ 

  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(window.orientation !== 0);
  });

})
```

Remember to inject the service `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` in your controller. In this example I injected `$scope` and `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` in the `AppCtrl`.

This works on iOS and Android!

Comment: How to inject service into controller?